# Nearly all internet traffic blocked aside from http/https

Tags: networking, home-networking

So today I noticed several network-based programs not functioning, such as Valve's Steam platform.  After disabling the windows firewall, and even booting in safe mode with networking, I am unable to get a response from www.google.com using the "ping" or "tracert" commands.  Connecting through the browser works fine however.  I have also tried on another laptop and have the same results.

This is using a wired internet connection in a multi-unit dwelling, so there must be one or more routers involved, but I cannot bypass them.  It appears to be a blockage at the router/ISP, but cannot believe someone would be so bold as to shut off ALL internet traffic aside from port 80/443.  Is there anything else I can do to test the network?

The ISP is comcast.  Should also mention that Skype is working fine.

```
Tracing route to www.google.com [74.125.239.49]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  TEW-731BR [192.168.10.1]
2     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  10.0.0.1
3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

Comment: Do you control the direct internet connection to comcast? As in, do you go through a building gateway (and as such have to confirm to policy applied on that) or do you have your own subscription to comcast?

Comment: Skype *can* work with only port 80 and 443 open, even if thi is not recommended. ([Source](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA148/which-ports-need-to-be-open-to-use-skype-for-windows-desktop)) This looks like a policy question more than a technical question. Whoever set up the network thought this was a good idea. Maybe they wanted to stop people from playing games and do p2p downloading. I think you should first talk to the person who set up the network.

Comment: I do not have a direct connection to the ISP.  There is some building gateway, at 10.0.0.1 which I can tell because that is what's returned on the 2nd hop from tracert:  `code` Tracing route to www.google.com [74.125.239.116]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms     3 ms     1 ms  TEW-731BR [192.168.10.1]
  2     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  10.0.0.1

Comment: Another piece of the puzzle. What does `tracert` output? Where does it stop? What does your assigned IP address look like?

Comment: Unfortunately, as nitro2k01 said, you will have to talk to the person who set up your network. This becomes a policy issue, and while it is possible to bypass these restrictions using technology. Your best solution is to talk to the person who runs the network to ask for clarification, and to see if it is possible to change the policy.

Comment: What's your external IP? Use a site like http://www.whatsmyip.org/ If you refresh a couple of times, does the IP address change? The decision to block most ports may have been one that the landlord or the contractor that installed the equipment did, not the actual ISP (Comcast).

Comment: thank you both for your help tracking down the issue. I'll check with the landlord about any recent policy changes